# Auction implementation similar to Dining Philosophers

Tags: netlogo, dining-philosopher

I am trying to implement an auction concept in netlogo - it is  similar to the [dining philosophers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) program.

My program deals with computers and processors that correspond to philosophers and forks in the dining philosopher program. In the philosophers program a user needs 2 forks to eat but in computers and processors, one computer needs one processor to work.

The states defined in my program are `IDLE`, `NEED`, `USING`, corresponding to `THINKING`, `HUNGRY`, `EATING` in the philosopher program.

Currently, my program goes to the point where all computers state changes to `NEED`. I am having issues in acquiring of server for the computers.

The code snippet is -

```
  // ... lines of code for declaration etc
  . 
  . 
  .
  to update 
  if state = "IDLE" [
     if random-float 1.0 < hungry-chance [
     set state "NEED"
  ]
  stop
  ]
  if state = "USING" [

  set total-used (total-used + 1)
     if random-float 1.0 < full-chance 

     [ release-servers ]

     set state "IDLE"
    stop
   ]
  if state = "NEED" 

     [ acquire-servers ]
       if we've got both forks, eat.
      if got? servers
     [ set state "USING" ]
   stop

 end
 //lines of code in between
 .
 .

  to acquire-servers  ;; philosopher procedure
    ask servers [
     if [owner] of servers = nobody[
     set owner myself
     move-to owner
     set heading [heading] of owner

     ]
   ]
 end
 // lines of code at end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! I've edited your question a bit to make it a bit easier to read.  I'm a bit confused how your problem is related to dining philosophers. That problem is specifically concerned with one user needing 2 resources and having the potential to 'lock' if everyone has one resource but no-one can get two to 'unlock' the situation. That would correspond to everyone in state `NEED`, and then you try strategies to prevent such a lock. But for your situation (1 resource for 1 computer), I don't see how the dining philosopher strategies help. Can you clarify?

Comment: In my program, the number of processors will be always be less than the number of computers. I am not handling the cooperation cases here. This program is simpler to the dinning philosopher. I just need ways to allocate processor to computer and when the computer is done, it releases the processor so that it can be assigned to other computer. Can you help in how do I implement this? As I said earlier in my post, currently the program goes till the point where computers are in state of need.

Comment: @RichardSnape could you please help

Comment: It's very hard to help you without the full code.  I could make a lot of assumptions about what servers / computers etc are and where total-used, hungry-chance etc are defined and the values they take, but it would be easier if you posted a link to your full working model saved as an nlogo file somewhere.

Comment: As it is - the code has lots of problems e.g.: 1. no procedure called release-servers 2. Not clear which agents have `state` or whether it's a global variable. Obviously I assume its `computers-own`.  In which case, you need to `ask` computer(s) in `update`, or show `go` where you do this 3. No comment on `if we've got both forks, eat` etc.  Are you basing this on the model in the samples library?  If so - we can maybe work out what to do

Comment: I can email you my program. Can you provide me your email id?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change your `if` for testing state into `ifelse` and remove the `stop` commands. That way, the computer will find its correct state and do the relevant procedures and then not look at the other states.

Second, the acquire-servers procedure currently assigns all the servers to the first computer that needs one. You probably want a procedure that looks more like:

```
to acquire-one-server
  let candidates servers with [ owner = nobody ]
  if any? candidates
  [ ask one-of candidates
    [ set owner myself
      move-to owner
      set heading [heading] of owner
    ]
  ]
end
```